# Is there a way to replaceView?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, replace, subview, addsubview

I have a UIScrollView with 2 subviews added to it. Now I wanna update the information displayed in one of the subviews. Is there a way to replace the existing subview with another view instead of addSubview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. There's no single method that will perform an atomic swap, but several combinations like this will do what you want:

```
[scrollView insertSubview:newView aboveSubview:oldView];
[oldView removeFromSuperview];
```